# Uploading excel file from IIS hosted asp application not uploading complete rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis

I have developed C# web application to upload excel file to SQL server. The targeted excel file has almost 265000 + Rows.
 When I upload it from localhost, all rows gets uploaded. I hosted the application in another computer using IIS ,and tried uploading only 19238 rows are getting uploaded.

The file size is 16Mb.

Here I copied sample code block, it is of no use though.

```
 private void bulkUpload()
    {
        btnUpload.Enabled = false;
        string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(ExcelFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
        ExcelFileUpload.SaveAs(excelPath);

        string conString = string.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(ExcelFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;

        }

        conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            string Sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();


            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + Sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }
            excel_con.Close();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.MBQ_All_1";

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Uniq", "Uniq");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("StoreClass", "StoreClass");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Store", "Store");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("code", "code");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ExtendedDescription", "ExtendedDescription");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ITEM_CLASS", "ITEM_CLASS");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SUPPLIER", "SUPPLIER");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Brands", "Brands");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Min", "Min");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Max", "Max");

                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                    con.Close();
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Your list uploaded successfully');", true);
                    lblExcelMsg.Text = "Your list uploaded successfully";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many rows are in `dtExcelData` when you set a breakpoint an examine the state of your program with the debugger?

Comment: 19238 rows it is showing while debugging the hosted application. Is it the problem with IIS?

Comment: IIS is the web server. That has very little to do with your issue. I suspect some sort of OleDbConnction limitation.

Comment: But While I run from visual Studio, the whole file gets uploaded.

Comment: Are you sure that `conString` is pointing to the correct file on the web server?

Comment: Yes, the same file

Comment: That doesn't seem right. There's a disconnect between the file you're uploading and the connection string you're using. Since they aren't directly tied to each other, it seems like you're looking at the file hardcoded in the connection string instead of the uploaded file. You should't be using a hardcoded connection string for this, you should be generating one on the fly based on the uploaded file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139450/discussion-between-alexander-and-mason).

Answer (score 1):

Added IMEX=1 with the Excel connection string and is uploading all rows now.